# React Native signed apk crash when Image with some sources, works fine in dev

Tags: android, react-native

When I run my app in debug mode
Everything works fine.

But when I make a signed apk using

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

It will run okay until it will encounter Image with source like this. The app will just crash, with only restart button:

```
<Image source={{uri: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Googlelogo.png"}} />
```

But with source like this it will NOT have any error

```
<Image source={{uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png"}} />
```

UPDATE: This error happens when Image is inside FlatList

UPDATE2: This error happens not only in FlatList. it happens with large images and resizeMode. If I set resize mode then my app will crash on a single image without FlatList, if I remove resizeMode then no error.

**The problem** that is happening in release build and I cant properly debug and find problem.

"react-native": "0.56.0"
"react": "16.4.1"

UPDATE: summary of the problem right now. React native android images takes a LOT of memory. So for example 200kb image can take of 20MB memory keep that in mind.

**UPDATE:** CRASH REPORT:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3036972 byte allocation with 2619648 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Bitmap.java)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:856)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:823)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.BitmapPool.alloc(BitmapPool.java:51)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.BitmapPool.alloc(BitmapPool.java:26)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.BasePool.get(BasePool.java:255)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.platform.ArtDecoder.decodeStaticImageFromStream(ArtDecoder.java:147)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.platform.ArtDecoder.decodeJPEGFromEncodedImage(ArtDecoder.java:127)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.decoder.DefaultImageDecoder.decodeJpeg(DefaultImageDecoder.java:173)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.decoder.DefaultImageDecoder$1.decode(DefaultImageDecoder.java:56)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.decoder.DefaultImageDecoder.decode(DefaultImageDecoder.java:119)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder.doDecode(DecodeProducer.java:254)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder.access$300(DecodeProducer.java:113)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder$1.run(DecodeProducer.java:152)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler.doJob(JobScheduler.java:202)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler.access$000(JobScheduler.java:22)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler$1.run(JobScheduler.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(PriorityThreadFactory.java:51)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: As you can see the difference in screen resolution. The first image is very large, while the second is more like an icon and has low resolution. Maybe the way you set up, means your app only accepts a maximum number of bytes off an image.

Comment: No. Size dosn't matter it will Crash with this image too http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/carlosjj/google-jfk/128/fonts-icon.png

Comment: Try another image which is 64x64(with not much color) , if that works then I think it's bytes issue.

Comment: It is working on development without problems with any images. Why It must have 64x64?? and no colors?

Comment: What version of react and react-native are you using?

Comment: "react-native": "0.56.0"

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No error messages. Also I found out that it happens only in FlatList item. If I put <Image> not in flatlist it will NOT have error.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug. But since it's related to `FlatList` then try these solutions https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15930

Comment: react-native "0.56.0" is has a lot of bugs, try to downgrade and test

Comment: UPDATE2: This error happens not only in FlatList. it happens with large images and resizeMode. If I set resize mode then my app will crash on a single image without FlatList, if I remove resizeMode then no error.

Comment: UPDATE: summary of the problem right now. React native android images takes a LOT of memory.  So for example 200kb image can take of 20MB memory keep that in mind.